# How to set the size for Amazon product page using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I made a python program and I would like to set the size of the product to click on the add to cart button. So to enable I should set the size. How can I set the size using selenium keys? Also, I would like this program to work for products that don't require to set the size, this program is working for this kind of products(for example [this product](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0118QC1BA))

So I would like to set the size to enable add to cart. The code should be after this line `(driver.get(url))`. I attached the program. I will appreciate any help.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

proxies = {
    'http': 'http://217.119.82.14:8080',
    'https': 'http://196.27.107.30:8080',
}

url = "https://www.amazon.com/Disney-Stitch-Surfer-Adult-T-shrt/dp/B072VPQ1BG/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1517916607&sr=8-4&keywords=t+shrt"

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxies)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\Andrei\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe",
                          chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="submit.add-to-cart"]/span/input').click()
```

Comment: What do you mean by *enable Add to cart button*?

Comment: I need to enable to click on it. Now it needs to set the size. So how can I set the size programmatically using selenium? Now you can't click on add to cart.

Comment: Try to add `sleep(3)` after `driver.get(url)`.

Comment: I added sleep(3) but it said To buy, select Size above Add to cart button. This is a T-Shirt so I need to set the size.

Comment: You should rewrite and clarify your question... it sounds like your actual question should be "How do I select a size?" to be more clear. Once you do that, post the code where you've attempted to set the size. I don't see that code in what you have currently posted. Limit the code to an [mcve].

Comment: Ok I will rewrite the code and the question. But if you enter the url from the program or run the program you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the item size directly by the id, but first, you need to click on the size menu

```
sizemenu = driver.find_element_by_id('dropdown_selected_size_name')
sizemenu.click()
select = driver.find_element_by_id('size_name_1') #Medium size
select.click()
```

to check if there is a menu on the page you can add

```
if driver.find_element_by_id('dropdown_selected_size_name') != 0:
```

---

```
if driver.find_element_by_id('dropdown_selected_size_name') != 0:
    sizemenu = driver.find_element_by_id('dropdown_selected_size_name')
    sizemenu.click()

    sleep(5)   

    select = driver.find_element_by_id('size_name_1') #medium size
    select.click()
    print("select size")
else:
    print("do nothing")


sleep(5)    
button = driver.find_element_by_id('submit.add-to-cart')
button.click()
```

Comment: *Amazon does not provide a select html tag, so it is not possible to use Select in this specific case*. Are you sure? You'd better to check again before claim that (-1)

Comment: i did it, and i try to use Select too

Comment: Check HTML source again and you will find `<select name="dropdown_selected_size_name" autocomplete="off" data-a-touch-header="Size" id="native_dropdown_selected_size_name" tabindex="-1" class="a-native-dropdown">`

Comment: hmm, I didn't notice that

Comment: I use this if driver.find_element_by_id('dropdown_selected_size_name') != 0: and I added the program that you write here to check if it on the t-shirt page but it doesn 't work. I use else and  in this statement I write this code driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="submit.add-to-cart"]/span/input').click() to add to cart if it is on the other page. Can you show me the if/else to check if is on the t-shirt page or else is on other page without that id? Because it doesn't work.

Comment: if didn't work, try to put a sleep between `sizemenu.click()` and `select size`

Answer (score 1):

To set required size you can use [Select](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#filling-in-forms) class:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.get(url)
# Create new object for drop down
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("native_dropdown_selected_size_name"))
# Select "Small" size
select.select_by_visible_text("Small")
wait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="add-to-cart-button" and not(@style="cursor: not-allowed;")]'))).click()
```

Comment: @AndreiGhervan, If you want to click "Add to cart" button right after size set you can explicitly wait for button to be clickable. Check updated code

Comment: Ok I will check it, thanks! How can I make an if statement to check if it on t-shirt page or on other page without size of product?

Comment: I mean this program should work for this kind of product without size (https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0118QC1BA/?tag=stackoverflow17-20) and for this kind of product with size(https://www.amazon.com/Disney-Stitch-Surfer-Adult-T-shrt/dp/B072VPQ1BG/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1517916607&sr=8-4&keywords=t+shrt)

Comment: Simply use `try`/`except` construction to check presence of select node

Comment: Ok I will try this. Thank you!